# Final Cut Pro: Is there a faster way to import frames onto a timeline?

Tags: video-editing, final-cut-pro

I'm rendering output from Blender into individual frames. Sometimes a single scene can have up to thousands of frames, each one a PNG file. I can import them all into an Event just fine, but when it comes to turning them into a compound clip I have to:

1. Select all the frames in the Library,
2. Click and drag them onto a project timeline (which takes 20-30 seconds with thousands of frames)
3. ^D and change the frame length of all the images to 1
4. ^G and name the compound clip.

Is there a faster way to do this, with less steps, and less manual intervention? Clicking and dragging the frames onto the timeline especially feels very primitive, and constantly changing the frame length to 1 every single time I do this also is annoying.